# Where to init Point variables/ Draw method gives warning

Tags: java, android

I have a Draw method which is as follows:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        a = new Point(0, 0);
        b = new Point(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2);
        c = new Point(canvas.getWidth(),0);




        path.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
        path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
        path.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
        path.lineTo(a.x, a.y);
        path.close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        canvas.rotate(36);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawText(text_to_disp, (canvas.getHeight()/4),0- 15, paint_text);

    }
```

The contention here is the init of Point variables, I get a warning in eclipse: `Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead)`

However I don't get reference to canvas in any other method in this class, how do I init these variables elsewhere?

I also have this method:

```
public void init(){

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        paint.setColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);
        path = new Path();
        path.setFillType(FillType.EVEN_ODD);

        paint_text = new Paint(); 
        helv_light = Typeface.createFromAsset(MainAct_Demo.con.getAssets(), pathHelv_light);
        paint_text.setTypeface(helv_light);
        paint_text.setTextSize(32);
        paint_text.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint_text.setColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);
    }
```

Comment: Get rid of the `Points` all together. Instead of `path.moveTo(a.x, a.y);` just use `path.moveTo(0, 0);` and instead of `path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);` just use `path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2);` etc.. Now you don't have to create 3 new objects each and every single time `onDraw()` is called, which could be A LOT.

Comment: Yes as I am using this in a list view, I can sense the lag.

Comment: You are basically creating 3 objects, inserting data into them, then immediately using that data you just inserted. You can cut out most of that process and just use the data directly.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting a warning to avoid allocations in a draw method is because the draw method could potentially be called many times in succession, such as during a scrolling or animation operation.  Object allocation is a fairly expensive process and is generally unnecessary in a primitive draw routine.

Allocate your Point objects in the constructor of your controller and store them as member variables.  Then in the draw method, you can assign their respective coordinates as required before using them

However, consider wether you actually need Point objects at all, considering you are just breaking them up into the primitive coordinates anyway.  Use simple float variables to calculate your width and height relative coordinates.

Comment: I am doing that in the init method, calling it from the constructor. But how can I reference the canvas outside of onDraw? Is there an efficient approach, I just want to draw a triangle on my listview rows.

Comment: Instantiate the Point objects in the init method, but set them all to 0,0.  Then in your draw method set the b.x = canvas.GetWidth(), etc.